# Inference on bootstrapped-confidence interval resulting in multimodal distribution

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, inference

I have a set of paired data that I am using to calculate a ratio.  The ratio is calculated as the sum of column 2 over the sum of column 1 (please see below)

```
Col1    Col2
3744519.37  0
2739505.37  0
46378122.62 0
2887639.57  78652.84
6000000 0
971112.48   0
7815969.01  0
11920577.36 0
2060120.66  0
4951863.34  0
8559269.86  0
4246529.62  0
54250000    0
17893683.49 0
1777305.52  0
1800832.37  0
2838034.29  0
15291266.83 0
3096538.88  0
2088767.28  0
5981199.57  0
2141878.34  0
1684058.06  0
2694327.27  0
7736276.87  0
3356067.88  0
1819461.59  0
972348.2    0
6922365 0
3357005.59  0
14870965.09 0
21500000    0
22419135    0
10000000    0
9250007.22  0
8900000 0
10404742.45 0
20452123.18 0
6340460.82  0
30494423.14 0
1157659.68  0
2868406.71  0
94257879.71 0
10369155.12 0
4315000 0
6158880 0
20057539.59 0
1335834.38  0
2406177.51  0
905846.54   405847
```

What I want to do is obtain a confidence interval from this point estimate to determine what the range of the population's ratio is.  I took the approach of doing a bootstrap in R (see below)

```
iterations = 10000

PCarray = c()

for (i in 1:iterations){

rows=sample(1:length(data$Col1), length(data$Col1), replace = TRUE)

numerator   =  0
denominator =  0
ratio = 0

for (j in 1:length(rows)){

numerator   =  numerator   +  data$Col2[rows[j]]
denominator =  denominator +  data$Col1[rows[j]]

}

ratio = numerator / denominator

PCarray = c(PCarray,ratio)

}

hist(PCarray,breaks=200)
```

Which ultimately gives me this graph:

[image: Bootstrap]

As before, I want calculate a confidence interval.  Is it alright just to do the percentile method to get a confidence interval (i.e. the upperbound is the 95th quantile and the lowerbound is the 5th quantile for a 90% CI)?  I realise the driver in the results is that only 2 values are non-zero, but is this an acceptable approach?  Is there any literature on this that states a confidence interval can be drawn from a non-symmetric, multimodal distribution?

Comment: Your code (and the corresponding display) doesn't match your second sentence. The code does $\sum \text{Col2}/\sum \text{Col1}$, while the second sentence of your post describes $\sum \text{Col1}/\sum \text{Col2}$. You should make your post consistent.

Answer (score 5):

The bootstrap is an asymptotic technique that assumes large sample sizes. Deviations from the expected asymptotic normal distributions are driven by the higher order moments of your data. You only have 50 points, which would've been fine if your data were OK-symmetric. But your data are hugely, **insanely**, HOPELESSLY skewed to the extent, I believe, that the sample skewness and kurtosis reach their [finite sample limits](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0204): skewness is 6.52 out of 6.86, kurtosis is 44.62 out of 48.02. That is, they can just as well be thought of as $+\infty$.

Essentially, all of your bootstrap samples fall into a small number categories:

1. Those that don't have any non-zero column two values, with probability $(48/50)^{50}=13.0\%$
2. Those that have the first non-zero value once, but never the second, with probability $\frac1{50} {50 \choose 1} (\frac{48}{50})^{49} = 13.5\%$
3. Those that have the second non-zero value once, but never the first one, with probability $\frac1{50} {50 \choose 1} (\frac{48}{50})^{49} = 13.5\%$
4. Those that have one of the non-zero values twice, with probability $(\frac2{50})^2 {50 \choose 2} (\frac{48}{50})^{48} = 27.6\%$
5. Those that have one of the non-zero values more than twice, with the remaining probability $\sum_{k=3}^50 (\frac2{50})^k {50 \choose k} (\frac{48}{50})^{50-k} = 32.4\%$

The first group is the point mass at zero; a histogram is a poor way to visualize this. The second and the third group provide the second peak around 0.0001 that you failed to observe (the histogram actually falls down to zero in the second bar, and picks up after that). Groups 4 and 5 provide the third peak around 0.0007. These probabilities are written in stone, and your histogram is almost pre-determined in shape by the composition of zeroes and non-zeroes in the sample. As such, a predetermined something is not a good estimator of an uncertain quantity. This is like saying, the temperature tomorrow will be 20C, without regard to the geography and season.

Bottomline: while the wheels of the bootstrap as a computational method do churn and generate some answers, the results are not statistically interpretable. The bootstrap does not approximate the sampling distribution of your statistic of interest well because, for the skewness and kurtosis of your distribution, your sample size is too small. May be $n=100,000$ or so would  have worked. But not $n=50$.

Answer (score 0):

First, yes, you can get confidence intervals for skewed distributions, or any distribution for that matter. A CI is defined by is exact, lower bound, or approximate coverage properties, not the shape of the underlying distribution.

However, you said you are trying to estimate the *range* of this variable from a sample using a nonparametric technique. This will not be possible. You have an *observed* range, but to estimate the true range, you need a model of the distribution of ratios, which by your use of the bootstrap, you indicate that you don't know this. Also, keep in mind the differrence between a *random variable* and a statstic of that random varaible. Bootstrapping is useful for estimating the variability of statistics, but not the actual data, which is what it is. Simple descriptive statistics and percentils should suffice for your problem, as stated.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Eupraxis1981.  I should of watched my language as I think I used range and confidence interval interchangeably.  But just to clarify, I want to know what is the confidence interval (at say 90%) that the true population statistic falls between, not what is the range of what it could be.  Also, would there be any advantage of using the mean of the bootstrapped distribution vs the 50th quantile if I had to set a single value of what I think the population's statistic value is?

Comment: I see. Actually, since you get a ratio of *exactly * $0$ quite often, that would be the best value for a single guess. One thing to check is the mean of the above distribution and compare it to the actual value you calculated. Is it close, or is there bias? Does that matter to you? As far as an interval, you should shift your distribution to the left by the value of your point estimate, then select percentiles from the distribution, e.g., 5% and 95% and form the interval $(\hat{est} - 95^{th},\hat{est} + 5^{th})$ for an approx. 90% CI.

Comment: Again, thank you so much for your response Eupraxis1981. My point estimate is: 0.0009031747 and the mean of the distribution is: 0.0009746227, a difference of 7.144796e-05 (as in the mean is slightly higher than the point estimate). What does this mean in the terms of a bias? If I knew that I would know if it mattered :).  Also, why do I need to shift my distribution to the left by the value of my point estimate? That would mean part of the distribution would go below 0 (good portion actually) and I wouldn't think this would ever be the case in the population (have a negative ratio). Thoughts?

Comment: This says that your estimator has a small chance of being biased high. Its hard tell with such small numbers, but in terms of percentages, your esimator is 7% high, not too bad. I wouldn't worry then. As for why you shift the distribution: you are bootstrapping to see the precision of your estimate of the population value. When you boostrap, you *know* that the true value is 0.0009031747, and you are forming hypothetical estimates from boostrap samples to see how close your estimator would be to 0.0009031747.

Comment: (cont'd) So, you subtract the "true" value (that of the sample, which is the empirical distribution we are using) to see how the estimates varies about this true value. The 95th percentile of this shifted distribution shows you the upper 5%, which typically will be cases where your estimator has *overestimated*. Therefore, you will need to subtract this form your esimator to extend the interval *down* to where the true value could be. Vice versa for the 5th percentile. Remember that with estimation, our statistic varies *about* the true value, not the other way around.

Comment: You are the cornucopia of bootstrapping knowledge :).  I did a bit of research to make sure I understand why you subract the "true value" and found this http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/402/lectures/08-bootstrap/lecture-08.pdf which discusses correcting for the statistical error on page 15 which says pretty much exactly what you wrote.  While I think I understand the logic, the inference is still confusing me.  For example, if my "true value" was 80 (the result of my intial sample) and when I bootstrapped it I ended up with a 90% CI of 40 to 120.

Comment: (cont'd) Now, if I were to subtract 80 from every one of the resampled estimates, I believe I would end up with a 90% CI of -40 to 40.  This is where I get a bit confused as what this is telling me is that the true population value falls between -40 and 40 which is quite far off from what I observed.  Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't calculate the CI  from the distribution of bootstrap  sample estimates you calculate it from the distribution of the bootstrap estimates minus the actual sample estimate then you take percentiles of THAT distribution